# Send POST JSON Data and Receive With Node.js (NO BODYPARSER)

Tags: html, node.js, json, send

I'm frustrated because I can't send from HTML or receive from Node.js JSON data. I think that I'm near to resolve, but I'm tired trying for hours. Anybody helps me?

As the code below, the responde is null (req.body = null?) in my VSCODE.

- When I try from Insomnia, that's ok. When I try from HTML Form, fails. *
  I could to use BodyParser, but why to send from Insomnia works and from HTML Form doesn't?

  ```js
  //routes.js
      routes.post('/go', (req, res) => {
         console.log(req.body)
         return res.json({ "Response": req.body })
      })
  ```

  ```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>API Correios</title>
         </head>

         <body>
            <form id="FrmQuery" action="http://localhost:3333/go" method="POST" enctype="application/json">
               <label for="sCepOrigem">Cep Origem</label><br>
               <input type="text" name="sCepOrigem" id="sCepOrigem"><br><br><br>

               <input type="text" id="jsonData"><br><br>

               <button id="send" type="button">Enviar</button>

            </form>  


            <script>
      document.querySelector('#send').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                  let sCepOrigem = document.querySelector('#sCepOrigem')
      
                  var obj = { 
                     "sCepOrigem": sCepOrigem.value, 
                  };
                  
                  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
      
                  document.querySelector('#jsonData').value = myJSON
                  document.querySelector('#FrmQuery').submit()
               })

            </script>

         </body>
      </html>
  ```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript from web browser you need to send it as raw XMLHttpRequest:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Other possibilities would be jQuery's `$.ajax` or maybe the new fetch API.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience with node js, I believe you have to simply `res.send` and cut out the return statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that I've tried this... can you show me an example?

Comment: For the new version of express i believe that body parser is needed to access req.body